# Serilog file sink from multiple servers has interleaved messages

Tags: asp.net, logging, serilog

I have a web app deployed across 10 web servers. They are all configured as such (note, the `path` below is a shared network path. So they are all pointing to the same log file):

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "shared": true,
          "path": "logs/foo_.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
  },
```

However I'm noticing the log file has interleaved messages:

> 2023-02-28 00:03:16.105 -06:00 [DBG] Execution plan of result filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.C2023-02-28 00:03:16.054 -06:00 [INF] Requ2023-02-28 00:03:16.130 -06:00 [DBG] Execution plan of result filters (in the following order):

Notice the `[DBG]` and `[INF]` log levels in the same message, and this here here specifically:

> Infrastructure.C2023-02-28 00:03:16.054 -06:00 [INF] Requ2023-02-28 00:03:16.13

How can I prevent this from happening? I thought `shared: true` was the support Serilog needed to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a frustrating answer, but unfortunately I don't think anything else is actually going to be good advice in the end. The bottom line is that logging over a network share is simply a bad idea - it's subject to network interference etc. Expecting multiple writes from multiple machines to coordinate well is making things harder again. This is not something that people do.

Serilog's success is going to be constrained by what the underlying filesystem's locking can offer.

You can read the source code of the sink to see which file sharing mode is employed at the .NET level. That in turn will map to Win32 API options.

If you can find a useful share mode configuration that works in your context, it can be suggested as an alteration to the sink, but such changes have to meet a very high bar - the `File` sink is used by literally millions of systems and the implementation is optimised for being easy to read and boring.

My recommendation is thus to either
a) shift to using a dedicated log server built for this purpose. e.g. Seq, or ELK based solutions. This is what people do. There are lots of other benefits:

- ease and speed of querying (querying based on tags and structured logs)
- ability to back up, archive, etc
- more predictable and reliable network usage to transmit the logs
  b) continue down the path of using files over a network, but use a machine-specific filename to remove this contention (I'm not certain that the `shared:true` will actually event work over the network though in the face of multiple processes)